# Create an offline page in oracle apex that would retrieve data from cache (Of Home page) when application goes offline

Tags: javascript, html, css, oracle-apex, progressive-web-apps

I want to create an offline page in oracle apex which should be the replica of homepage and get the latest data from the cache.
I came to know about service workers in apex 22.1 but don't know how to use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I never did that (didn't have to) so I don't have my own experience to share.

However, you might want to take a look at **Vincent Morneau**'s blog named [APEX as a PWA](https://vmorneau.me/apex-pwa-part1/) (Progressive Web App) which consists of 8 chapters:

- Part 1: Introducing PWA
- Part 2: Setup and Development Tips
- Part 3: JavaScript Recap
- Part 4: Installing an APEX App into a Mobile Device
- Part 5: **Using an APEX App Offline**
- Part 6: Handling Background Sync
- Part 7: Sending Push Notifications
- Part 8: Final Thoughts

Although "Part 5" talks specifically about what you're asking ("I want to create an offline page"), I'd suggest you to read it all. It is well explained so I hope you'll manage to make it work. Best of luck!